# Display available products in the category not the products created by categeory

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having the category of

```
Category1 (25)
Category2 (3)
Category3 (16)
```

in that

```
Category1 have totally 25 products but the product available is 8,
Category2 have totally 3  products but the product available is 1,
Category1 have totally 16 products but the product available is 7,
```

so now I need to display the count of available products , for that how I achieve this.

I need the output of

```
Category1 (8)
Category2 (1)
Category3 (7)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: Thanks for the response and here you find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621593/count-only-active-products-in-magento.